# ros2: command not found

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to run ros2 iron irwini on Ubuntu 22.04.1 by using the ros2 documentation guide for ubuntu.
I source the setup file like this: `. ~/ros2_iron/install/local_setup.bash` and then run a test program `ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp talker`. I keep getting `ros2: command not found` as a result. I have tried reinstalling ros2, and change `local_setup.bash` to `local_setup.sh` and `local_setup.zsh` when I source, but to no avail. Does anyone know what else I can try or what I'm doing wrong here?
Thank you.

Comment: Most likely the executable is not part of your `PATH`. Either add the directory to your path or execute the command with full path or from the directory as `./ros2`.

Comment: Thank you. I added the directory to the path, and tried executing the command with the full path but I still get ros2: command not found.

Comment: Kindly show `ls -l /full/path/to/ros2` and how you executed it.

Comment: I must have done something wrong somewhere lol, because I get no such file or directory when I run that. I added export PATH="/Directory1:$PATH" in the bash file.

Comment: It seems you are not yet familiar with absolute and relative paths. [A small introduction](https://linuxhint.com/absolute-relative-paths-linux/). I'd refrain from using relative paths in the `PATH` variable.

Comment: thank you, I will take a look. I'm very new to Linux, so thank you for your patience and help.